# WPF TabControl - Do I need an ItemTemplateSelector *and* a ContentTemplateSelector?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, contenttemplateselector, itemtemplateselector

So I have as the main user control in my WPF app a `TabControl` that will support several different views (basically forms for data entry) and their underlying view models (basically ORM mappings.)

I built a `ContentTemplateSelector` to throw out the correct content view for the selected item.

So my question is:

Should I build an `ItemTemplateSelector` to select the correct property from the underlying view model that will act as the tab header title?

Or, should I assign a property from each view model to another property called something like DisplayTitle and then use that in the `ItemTemplate`?

And more generally, is there a way to combine the "selection" of an ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate under a single selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [type based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) data-templating for the content and a common property (set as `DisplayMemberPath`) or an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) on the class for the header (in case there is one item per class).

I doubt that you can conveniently combine the selectors, nor do i like selectors in general...